# How to crop images to remove excess background using image mask?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have two images of a person standing up: one original RGB image with the person and background and the mask/alpha matte for that image displaying only the silhouette of the person. So far I have been able to remove the excess padding from the masked imaged via cropping using the function below.

```
def crop_excess(image):
    y_nonzero, x_nonzero = np.nonzero(image)
    return image[np.min(y_nonzero):np.max(y_nonzero), np.min(x_nonzero):np.max(x_nonzero)]
```

Now I would like to use the cropped mask and impose it on the original RGB image so that the excess background is removed.

[Example images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnD5j.png)

Any ideas on how this could be done?

Comment: you have to use the same values to crop original image - so maybe better return `np.min(y_nonzero), np.max(y_nonzero), np.min(x_nonzero), np.max(x_nonzero)`  from function and use these values with original image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get values from mask and use it on both images

```
y_nonzero, x_nonzero = np.nonzero(image)

y1 = np.min(y_nonzero)
y2 = np.max(y_nonzero)
x1 = np.min(x_nonzero)
x2 = np.max(x_nonzero)

cropped_image = image[y1:y2, x1:x2]

cropped_original_image = original_image[y1:y2, x1:x2]
```